# Conver PYWEBIO to a Public Web Address

Tags: python

Have created a pywebio for BMI, but only obtained a temporary local host web address prompt instead of a permanent public web address.

Could you advise on how to create a public web address, please?

Have seen ways such as start_server, but doesn't work for me.

Please find BMI codes here.

```
pip install pywebio
from pywebio.input import input, FLOAT
from pywebio.output import put_text

def bmi():
    height = input("Input your height(cm)：", type=FLOAT)
    weight = input("Input your weight(kg)：", type=FLOAT)

    BMI = weight / (height / 100) ** 2

    top_status = [(16, 'Severely underweight'), (18.5, 'Underweight'),
                  (25, 'Normal'), (30, 'Overweight'),
                  (35, 'Moderately obese'), (float('inf'), 'Severely obese')]

    for top, status in top_status:
        if BMI <= top:
            put_text('Your BMI: %.1f. Category: %s' % (BMI, status))
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bmi()
    
start_server([bmi])
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to do it. The idea is that right now your server is on localhost (your private computer AKA offline). You want to expose the pywebio application to everyone on your local network.

To do this you need to edit the start_server part of your code to this:

```
start_server(bmi, port=which_ever_port_you_want, host="Server_IP_address")
```

for example if you had your application running on a raspberry pi (with IP 192.168.0.11) and wanted to access it using your laptop you would do this:

```
start_server(bmi, port=8990, host="192.168.0.11")
```

and access it using your browser to 192.168.0.11:8990